# Creating a Scrolling Nav in Angular 7

Tags: css, angular7, angular-animations

I'm trying to build a scrolling navbar in my Angular 7 app.

The functionality should be like this:

When the user clicks on any of the navbar links, the page will scroll **smoothly** to that section (with that specific ID), and the navbar link should have an active class.

Also when the user scrolls to that section the menu link should also be updated with the active class (based on the OffsetY for example)

something like this:
[Scrolling Nav](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/scrolling-nav/)

Comment: And where did you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the scrollTo window function to get the wanted behavior:

[scrollTo](https://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/scroll.html)

About the perfect approach, to get the exact pixels I am not sure.